# How to import picture in flash with transaprent background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, import

How do I make transparent background to imported image in flash, because now i imported it and image has white box around it.

code for adding images to stage

```
var imageBD = (Math.floor(Math.random()*2))? new Trees() : new Rocks;
            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            var BD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageBD.width, imageBD.height);
            BD.draw(imageBD);
            bitmap.bitmapData = BD;
            bitmap.width = mRadius * 2 * mToPx;
            bitmap.height = mRadius * 2 * mToPx;
            bitmap.x = pxStartX;
            bitmap.y = pxStartY;
            this.addChild(bitmap);
            obstacleImages.push(bitmap)
```

Since i'm mew i cannot post images so i'm giving you a link to image:http://prntscr.com/pugdl

Comment: What format is your pictures saved in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically tell the `BitmapData` ([docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData%28%29)) object to be transparent.

In your case, replace this line:

```
var BD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageBD.width, imageBD.height);
```

...with this:

```
var BD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(imageBD.width, imageBD.height, true, 0x00000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image itself has transparency.  General file types for these kinds of images are **PNG** or **GIF**.

You shouldn't have to do anything for Flash to find the transparency.

Comment: i have that all and if i use loader to load it it is trasnaprent, but if i imported it in flash and gave it a class and than call by code it's not transparent.